# Unity3d Run In Background setting not working in fullscreen standalone

Tags: unity, networking

I've ran in to an odd issue with my Unity3D game completely pausing in certain scenarios, even with the Run In Background player setting on.

For reference I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate using Unity 4.3.3

**In The Editor:** 
If I tab out of the editor while the game is running everything keeps working fine.

*In Windowed Mode:*** 
If I'm running the standalone in windowed mode and tab out, everything keeps working fine.

However, if I grab the top bar on the window to move the window around, the game pauses until I release the window. Nothing updates, nothing runs while it's paused.

**In Fullscreen Mode:**
If I'm running the standalone in fullscreen mode and alt+tab out the game pauses. Not resuming until I tab back in to the game.

This is causing issues with the multiplayer aspects of my game, because the client stops sending messages to the server whenever they alt+tab out or move the window.

I know the graphics device is getting lost when I tab out, because I get this error in my log:

> HandleD3DDeviceLost
>     HandleD3DDeviceLost: still lost
>   Skipped rendering frame because GfxDevice is in invalid state (device lost)

But that should only cause the game to stop rendering, which is fine. I just need the update loop to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out this was a Unity bug. I reported it to Unity and they confirmed it for me. Not much to do besides wait for the next update.